# Numpy: Storing array data to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, file

So I have my two arrays and need to write them to a file called 'output.dat' such that I could then read the data from each array in that file and plot the data with pyplot.

Comment: typically it helps if you provide some evidence of trying to solve your problem

Comment: you can use pickle standard library for doing this

Answer (score 2):

The `numpy.save()` function can be used to store the file, as:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

# Note: The standard convention is to store as a .npy file.
with open('output.dat', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, x)
```

The `numpy.load()` function can be used to retrieve the file, as:

```
with open('output.dat', 'rb') as f:
    x = np.load(f)

>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The [docs can be found here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).